# What is TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH equivalent in PyTorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I have been working with Tensorflow for years, just started working with PyTorch. I was wondering if there is an environment variable like `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH` in Tensorflow,a function or anything to allow GPU growth in PyTorch.